# Storyboards not reusing cell. How do I force it to reuse a cell in uitableview?

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, storyboard

I'm using XCode 4.2 and iOS 5.0 with simulator.
For the purpose of my test I created a new empty project and linked it to a tableview in the storyboard, assigned an identifier for the cell and call that cell from cellForRowAtIndexPath.
Inside of cellForRowAtIndexPath I created a single log line to test this and the problem is that every time you scroll up or down a new cell is created.

How can I force it to reuse the cells and not generate a new one every time it scrolls?

The only methods I have are the default ones generated by xcode when subclassing UITableViewController (so initWithStyle, viewDidLoad, viewDidUnload, numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath)

Thanx a lot.
Eduardo.

Comment: how many rows are you returning in numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: can you post some code in here of what you are doing in cellForRowAtIndexPath ?